# Exchange data with tablet and devices in charging and withount charging

Tags: android, permissions, usb, tablet

My tab Levovo TB-8505F have a odd behavior. When charging is in progress, it exchanges data with my device. When  harged up to 100%
for some reason the tablet doesn't want to exchange data with device and says No Permission. I expect opposite behavior: it tranfer data when charging is over and not can not transfer when charging. How i can run exchanges data when device not charging?

This is my manifest :

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <permissions>
       <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
    </permissions>
...
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
...
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
```